# Pass URL with single quote and ampersand in Outlook using a .NET website

Tags: c#, email, outlook, exchange-server

I have a web page that uses a webmail service to send emails.  This is on an company intranet using a Microsoft Exchange server.  My website created an email with a link to an image handler on my website.  In my code, I can print some debug messages and I see:

```
<img src='http://tav.target.com/VIBEHandler.ashx?id=z064441_45975&type=Amazing'/>
```

But in the email, when I view the source code, I see this:

```
<img src="http://tav.target.com/VIBEHandler.ashx?id=z064441_45975&amp;type=Amazing"/>
```

My single quotes changed to double quotes (no big deal).

```
&
```

changed to

```
&amp;
```

This causes the URL to not work and images appear as the red "x", indicating a missing image.

How can I preserve my URL?

Comment: You need to show how you build the HTML body and pass it to Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution we could come up with is to use a single variable with multiple values separated with an underscore.  This eliminates the need for the '&' symbol entirely and makes everything happy and compatible.

The URL is basically a link to an image handler so we can include images in emails without the use of attachments, shared drives, etc.  The image handler can also do things like merge images together to create a single image (WAY better than trying to overlap images in emails which almost NEVER works).  I simply added some code to the image handler that can check for and dissect the "meta-variable" in my URL.

http://sample.com?var=ONE_TWO_THREE
http://sample.com?var1=ONE&var2=TWO&var3=THREE

The URL now looks more clean and can have as many variables as I want so long as I put everything in the exact correct order, read it all in using the same sequence, don't miss anything, and document everything well.  I COULD go one step farther and specify what each variable means:

http://sample.com?var=first-Nicolai_last-Dutka_age-34_etc-foobar

But that just tells the whole world what all my variables mean!  Hypothetically, I could do:

http://sample.com?var=24154#kja*&nl897q45pjkh8&*&^HJ435

Then it would be up to me to determine where the breaking points are to bust that up into the variables:

24151, kja*, n1897, 45, etc

Of course, I'm not going to be that complex and will likely just stick to:

http://sample.com?var=ONE_TWO_THREE

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd party emailing service might be converting your HTML document to a valid XML document for compatibility reasons.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Basically, in XML, an ampersand character represents and XML entity, and can not be used unless you place the text within a CDATA node. Your 3rd party service seems to just be converting the & to &amp; , which would work to safely display the value, but doesn't do too much for a URL.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

If I were in your situation, I would URL encode the image URL when generating the HTML document that is being sent out. This way, it is both a proper link, and a valid XML string.

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myUrlString);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: We tried the UrlEncode among many other things and none of it works.  The URL is getting scrubbed and the '&' being replaced sometime after the email is out of our hands.